# Como cargar un Intent desde fuera de un Activity C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, recyclerview, activity

Tengo una clase llamada `PhotoAlbumAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter` donde se crean, asignan y configuran los recursos de un RecyclerView que contiene imagenes de clientes pero esta clase esta fuera de la `public class` `MainActivity : Activity` .

Aca tengo el metodo `OnClick` que se gatilla obviamente al hacer click en una de las imágenes del RecyclerView y guardo en variables publicas/globales el ID de la imagen que se selecciono. Mi problema reside en que no tengo idea de como con los resultados ya obtenidos del OnClick cargar otra clase donde me carga los detalles de ese cliente.

Intente con:

```
             var Intent = new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(Detalles));
             StartActivity(Intent);
```

Pero no funciona a menos que este en `MainActivity : Activity` o en otro Activity. El error me dice que no existe en el contexto actual.

Alguna idea de como gatillar mi otro Activity Detalles.cs aparte de esta?

Adjunto codigo.

```
public class PhotoViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
        public TextView Caption { get; private set; }
        public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> listener)
            : base(itemView)
        {
            Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
            Caption = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);

            itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.LayoutPosition);
        }
    }

    public class PhotoAlbumAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

        PhotoAlbum mPhotoAlbum;

        public PhotoAlbumAdapter(PhotoAlbum photoAlbum)
        {
            mPhotoAlbum = photoAlbum;
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
            Inflate(Resource.Layout.LCardView, parent, false);

            PhotoViewHolder vh = new PhotoViewHolder(itemView, OnClick);
            return vh;
        }

        public override void
            OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            try
            {
                PhotoViewHolder vh = holder as PhotoViewHolder;

                vh.Image.SetImageBitmap(GetImageBitmapFromUrl(mPhotoAlbum[position].PhotoID));
                vh.Caption.Text = mPhotoAlbum[position].Caption;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string LineErrorNumber = Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7);
            }
    
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return mPhotoAlbum.NumPhotos; }
        }


void OnClick(int position)
            {
                try
                { 
                    VarGlobal.gIdRecyclerMaterial=(position); //Id inciando de 0.
                    Busqueda.Globales.IdSeleccionado = Convert.ToInt32(mPhotoAlbum[position].TipoMaterial.Substring(2)); //Obteniendo ID de A, P o S.


                       char c = mPhotoAlbum[position].TipoMaterial[0]; //Obteniendo primera letra para saber si es A, P o S.
                        VarGlobal.gNombreMaterialR = Convert.ToString(c);
        
                        //Gatillar detalles... 
//********************************************************************************
                       
                        //var Intent = new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(Detalles));
                        //StartActivity(Intent);
    
                    
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    string LineErrorNumber = Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7);
                }
            }        
    
            private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
            {
                Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
    
                using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                    if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                    {
                        imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                    }
                }
    
                return imageBitmap;
            }
    
        }
    }
```